# Videos streaming with JW Player not working

Tags: streaming

I found recently that any site that streams videos using JW Player that the player gives me a message in my browser saying "Click here to install Java".
I confirmed that I do have IcedTea-web Plugin installed and I went to a java testing site here: http://javatester.org/version.html and it shows that I have it installed.  But I still keep getting the message that I need to install Java on a site that streams a video using JW Player.  This just started happening a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Java implementations are the same (thank god for universal standards, right?). There are many different versions of Java that you can install on your system and every version really is different.

Your best luck to get it working, is to install Java from Oracle. There are many links online to show you how to do this (e.g. http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux). Should this link not work, just google "Oracle java ubuntu" and you'll get proper working links.

Please follow the instructions carefully.